# android get current activity's name for polymorphic method

Tags: android, class, methods, android-activity, compare

I have a dilemma, basically I have ImageButtons that I want to be displayed on all activities (this is done) and I also want them to be displayed on all activities a certain way, depending on which activity is being displayed. I want this to be done in a way that I don't have to hardcode the specifications individually in each class.

Although the images are defined in one shared XML document, I want a shared class to be able to read which activity is being called, and then format a particular image a certain way. This is so if I change the functionality, I only have to change attributes in one class.

I want to do some sort of If or switch statement that compares if( thisActivity == MainActivity ) then, but I don't know how to retrieve the "names" of the activities to compare them!

edit. I want something like this:

```
   Context myContext = this;

    if(myContext instanceof Intent(MainMenu.class) == true)
    {

    }
```

I know the Intent function doesn't have a prototype to check a class like that, but I want something that will let me know the current class is part of a particular class, as opposed to several other cases in the conditional statement

thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Will the `instanceof` operator suit your needs?

```
if(this instanceof Activity1) {
//...
}
else if(this instanceof Activity2) {
//...
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? How would I use that operator in a conditional statement and what would I be comparing?

Comment: lol, wow we both edited our posts at the same time. see my edit: I applied it, but I wasn't sure what type Activity1 is supposed to be?

Comment: Updated. You just use the `this` reference to the current Activity and can compare the class name of any other Activity (or any other Object, for that matter).

Comment: `Context myContext = this; 
  
     if(myContext instanceof Activity(Main.class))
     {
      
     }`  ?? I'm missing something about how to pull the name of the activity that I'm looking for. what type is "Activity1" in your example and how do I initialize it?

Comment: I have `if(this instanceof Activity)` which returns no errors, it just isn't specific enough, currently every time its run all "this" will be instance of "Activity", I'm not sure how to change the distinctions in this case

Comment: Really? Use your class names! Whatever classes you're using that extend Activity, just use that. If your class is called `ThisIsMyClassActivity extends Activity` just use `if(this instanceof ThisIsMyClassActivity)`. YOU CAN USE ANY CLASS NAME.